# Distinct not returning expected result?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

What wrong with this code (or my sanity for that matter :D ).

The **Distinct** clause in the Select statement is NOT working. It's result set contains All rows for Each EmpID in ej. Please help!!

```
Declare @SurveyID int;
SET @SurveyID = 2;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL     DROP TABLE #t 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL     DROP TABLE #t1 


SELECT  Distinct(ej.EmpID),
        ej.JobCode,
        ej.SurveyID,
        ej.IsCompleted,
        Coalesce(ej.Declined,0) AS Declined,
        emp.Company,
        emp.UserID,
        emp.LoginRecord,
        count(JobCode) AS Benchmark
    into #t
    FROM SAS.EmployerJobs ej
        INNER JOIN SAS.Employer emp
            ON ej.EmpID = emp.EmpID
    Where (ej.SurveyID = @SurveyID)
    GROUP BY ej.EmpID, ej.JobCode, ej.SurveyID, ej.IsCompleted, Declined, emp.Company, emp.UserID, emp.LoginRecord
    Order by ej.EmpID ASC

Select * from #t

drop table #t
```

Comment: I am seeing all rows for each EmpID returned isntead of one row per EmpID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only require one row for each distinct EmpID in the result set, then you need to decide how to aggregate the multiple rows of data (multiple jobs) for each EmpID. For example, choosing the minimum value.

But from the names and relations, it seems that an EmpID can have multiple jobs, so it doesn't seem to make sense to expect only one row per EmpID if you want also to list the individual jobs.

UPDATE: To count the number of JobCodes

```
SELECT  ej.EmpID,
        ej.SurveyID,
        emp.Company,
        emp.UserID,
        emp.LoginRecord,
        count(JobCode) AS Benchmark
    into #t
    FROM SAS.EmployerJobs ej
        INNER JOIN SAS.Employer emp
            ON ej.EmpID = emp.EmpID
    Where (ej.SurveyID = @SurveyID)
    GROUP BY ej.EmpID, ej.SurveyID, emp.Company, emp.UserID, emp.LoginRecord
    Order by ej.EmpID ASC
```

Your original query attempted to pull in data that varies per job, and that is why you were not getting the aggregation. (E.g. IsCompleted, declined etc..) For aggregation to work, only include data that is an aggregate of the job data, like `count(JobCode)`, or doesn't vary per job, such as employer attributes.

Comment: Very Good explanation. It helped to clarify my approach. I should aggregate on EmployerJobs table and THEN do the inner join with Employer to translate the ID to meaningful name for reporting.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot select distinct on specific columns in SQL Server.

Because of this SQL Server is returning every distinct combination of columns.  What you are asking it to do is arbitrarily drop data that you have told it to select.

If you want it to start dropping out records then you will need to specify which ones you want.  One way to do this is to specify MIN or MAX values for the columns that you do not want repeated.

I tend to avoid doing this because in my experience most of the time when this this is happening it is because of weird logic in the query.  Without seeing your source data and knowing your business rules it would be hard to tell you how to change your query.

**UPDATE:**

based on your comment:

> Business rule is to count number of JobCodes (as Benchmarks) for each
>   EmpID in EmployerJobs Table (after filtering on SurveyID).

I would change your query to this:

```
SELECT  EmpID,
        COUNT(DISTINCT JobCode)
FROM SAS.EmployerJobs 
Where SurveyID = @SurveyID
GROUP BY EmpId
```

This will return every `EmpId` along with the number of distinct `JobCode`s associated with that ID.  If the business rule you gave me is accruate then the rest of your query is exactly the kind of weird logic that I was talking about.

Comment: Business rule is to count number of JobCodes (as Benchmarks) for each EmpID in EmployerJobs Table (after filtering on SurveyID).

Comment: Is count(distinct ...) required here? Count(*) should be sufficient unless employees can be associated multiple times with the same job.

Comment: If your assumption that employees cannot be associated with the same job multiple times is correct then yes, you are right.  This would be a guaranteed way to get a count of distinct `JobCode`s associated with an `EmpId`.

Comment: Thank you Abe. My second day of lurking; first post and I'm in love with this site already :)

Comment: Glad to hear it @udp1024.  You won't find a better place to get help.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct is not a function. See here for a great explanation.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/12/sql-distinct-group-by.aspx

The distinct keyword as you have used it will only ensure that no duplicates over all of the returned columns will be included in the result set.

Use a group by clause to get your desired result.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Note that you will need to use an aggregate function (sum, max, avg for example) on any columns in the select clause that you do not include in th group by clause.

If you want the results to include only a single row for each employee ID then that is the only column that you should include in the group by clause.

Try this (note that a temp table adds no value here and has been removed).

```
SELECT  
    EmpID, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    SAS.EmployerJobs  
Where 
    SurveyID = @SurveyID 
GROUP BY 
    EmpId
```

Note: Go with Abe Miessler's answer if it is possible for an employee to be associated multiple times with the same job.

Comment: Thanks. That tells me what's wrong. Now how can I aggregate on EmpID without using Distinct??

Comment: Thanks for the help Scott. I learned a lot in a few short minutes!! I am glad I signed up to this site - very helpful and knowledgeable people here :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want it to do?   Why do you have a Distinct and a Group By?

```
    SELECT  
    ej.EmpID, 
    ej.JobCode,
    ej.SurveyID,
    ej.IsCompleted,
    Coalesce(ej.Declined,0) AS Declined,
    emp.Company,
    emp.UserID,
    emp.LoginRecord,
    count(JobCode) AS Benchmark
    FROM SAS.EmployerJobs ej
    INNER JOIN SAS.Employer emp
        ON ej.EmpID = emp.EmpID
    Where ej.SurveyID = '2'   
    GROUP BY ej.EmpID, ej.JobCode, ej.SurveyID, ej.IsCompleted, Declined, emp.Company,  emp.UserID, emp.LoginRecord       
    Order by ej.EmpID ASC
```

Comment: Thanks udp1024, I had the same answer you accepted up first.  But I am cool with mdma get the points.